# Assigning one event handler to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

Ok, I've gone through the suggested q/a but they didn't seem to answer this clearly or at all.

I would like to reduce clutter and have one event handler assigned to several images at once, rather than separately. This is the current code with repetitive code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#div1 img:eq(0)").mouseenter(function(){
                     $(this).css("border","1px solid green"); 
     })

      $("#div1 img:eq(1)").mouseenter(function(){
                     $(this).css("border","1px solid green); 
     })

      $("#div1 img:eq(2)").mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).css("border","1px solid green"); 
     })
```

})

In plain javascript I might've done something like:

```
div1imgs=documentGetElementById("div1").getElementsByTagName("img");

for(i=0; i<div1imgs.length; i++) {
 div1imgs[i].onmouseover=function(){this.style.border="1px solid green"}
```

It's tempting to just use that, but I'm getting into jquery and prefer to keep it jquery. Is there some equivalent solution in jquery, that's hopefully even simpler that assigns an event handler to a group of images simultaneously? Also uses a loop, or otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your vanilla js version it would be this:

```
$("#div1 img").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css("border","1px solid green"); 
});
```

Note, when you use jQuery to bind an event to multiple elements, it will automatically loop through each individual element to perform the binding.

Comment: Thanks, kind of suspected it would be simple.

Comment: Yeah. The beauty of jQuery is that it does a lot of things for you behind the scenes. As long as you have a grasp on the basics of JS, it is safe to use, and in many cases more efficient. Don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped :).